# compile objective-c to java

Tags: java, objective-c, cross-compiling

I was wondering if there is a way to compile objective-c code to Java. I am fully aware of the fact that both languages differ greatly, yes, but considering it is possible to reuse Java code in Objective-C, I wondered if you can export the Objective-C code to a JAR, or something else reusable in a Java application.

Anybody any thoughts?

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185334/is-there-a-good-java-to-objective-c-converter

Comment: It is not the language that makes this impractical, but the class libraries around them. The two ecosystems developed in drastically different directions, so you will be better off manually porting your code or re-building it from scratch, with Objective C serving as an inspiration.

Comment: Well, first one wonders -- WHY???  But, yes, you could, with great effort, create an Objective-C execution environment in Java and translate the source to Java or Java bytecodes.  But WHY???

Comment: Well, that covers it the other way around, but I can see why you pasted that link. However, I still think it's a valid question: I am not interested in a 'push the button and you have a Java application' export -- much rather, I want to export certain logic to be reused in a Java application. Think of it as the same way you would use C libraries in Java.

Comment: Why? Because if it is possible, I could build an iPhone app, and export the basic funtionality and reuse it in an Android app. Seems to me that's prett useful, and logical.

Comment: "useful" perhaps but impossible. Move along, there's nothing to see here.

Comment: @gloris - C libraries used in Java is not the same as compiling C code to Java - if you just need to call ObjC libraries then wrap those libraries in a C API and then call from Java as you would any other C library

Comment: @Mark: that seems feasible. Have you tried this already?

Comment: @Mark: do you know of any documentation available on this subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open-source project Objc2J, it can help you.

http://code.google.com/p/objc2j/

**Disclaimer:** I am an author of this unfinished product.

Comment: Great! It'll probably take a while before this project is fully launched, by I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: Hi gjoris, have you used this objc2j. Can you help how to convert entire project using this?

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, it looks like the goal is not actually to compile Objective-C to Java, but actually to compile Objective-C for Android.

For compiling to Android, [Apportable](http://www.apportable.com/) is a solution that has been used to build and deploy [several Objective-C apps](http://www.apportable.com/customers) to Android marketplaces.

Comment: This is used only for games.

Comment: The Apportable technology is general and is used for more than games. That games is the most popular use case is primarily for business reasons.

Comment: I guess this is because nobody likes "alien" UIs on Android?

Comment: Depends on the app - and Apportable is continuing to progress on various UIKit options

Comment: Well, there's one simple example: most iOS apps have a button to navigate back. On Android this is excessive, because it has system "back" button. Does Apportable handle this simple thing? And there are much more more complex differences.

Comment: Wiring up the back button is a typical Apportable porting task. Docs are here - http://docs.apportable.com/uikit-extensions

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps but [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch/) is probably what you're looking for.

It's C# based but I believe compiles natively for both iOS and Android.

Comment: Not really. I want to export actual libraries from Objective-C, and reuse them in Java. But thanks for the info! I only knew PhoneGap thusfar.